# Fancybox dialog clickthrough

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have a page from which a user can submit a short form requesting a quote. I don't want to lose the page context, so I'd like to open that form in a dialog window and allow them to submit from there. This all kind of works, but I'm having problems with both the iframe and ajax implementations. Specifically:

1. I can't get the iframe implementation to resize to its content.
2. I can't get the ajax implementation to submit the form *within* the dialog.

When the form is submitted, I want the dialog to remain open so that I can display any form errors or a thank you/success message for the user. They would then be able to resubmit or close the dialog.

I haven't been able to find a way to make this work. I don't particularly care which implementation I use, but I need the user experience to be decent. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the public method `$.fancybox.resize`, documented [here](http://fancybox.net/api).

Submitting the form inside the FancyBox can be done in different ways. I personally prefer to do an AJAX submission and display the results using a callback. [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/XBeP7/1/):

```
$(function(){
    var form = '\
    <form action="/" method="post">\
        <label>\
            Enter something:<br>\
           <input type="text" name="textbox" />\
        </label>\
        <input type="submit" value="OK" />\
    </form>';

    $.fancybox({
        content: form,
        onComplete: function(){

            $.fancybox.resize(); // Not needed, just for demo

            $('#fancybox-content form').submit(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://fiddle.jshell.net/echo/jsonp/',
                    type: 'json',
                    success: function(d){

                        // The "d" object here would be populated

                        $.fancybox({
                            content: 'Thanks for submitting!'
                        });
                    }
                });

                return false;
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your jsfiddle script doesn't work (no that there is something *wrong* with it). You haven't linked to a fancybox script.